# Как посредством отложенной функции в Битрикс передать переменную?

Tags: битрикс

В шаблоне компонента (откуда нужно передать данные):

```
<?php $this->SetViewTarget('nav_page_count');?>
<?php $APPLICATION->AddViewContent('nav_page_count', $arResult["NavPageCount"]);?>
<?php $this->EndViewTarget('nav_page_count');?>
```

В header.php нужно получить эти данные и передать параметром в метод.

Делаю так:

```
<?=Tools::setMetaPagination($APPLICATION->ShowViewContent('nav_page_count'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_GET['PAGEN_1'])?>
```

Параметр передается, тут все хорошо. Но, тут же выводятся эти данные в браузере! Мне не нужно печатать их в браузере, почему так происходит?

Мне нужно взять из шаблона переменную с неким значением и в header.php подставить ее в качестве параметра. Как это реализуется?

Answer (score 0):

> Мне не нужно печатать их в браузере, почему так происходит?

так происходит потомучто код в шапке страницы **уже** отработал, в том числе добавил в массив буферизованых областей твою область nav_page_count

всё что теперь можно сделать - только подменить **содержимое** этой области, что у тебя и происходит

'прокинуть' вверх по коду значение переменной нельзя

тебе нужно менять архитектуру страницы и высчитывать нужное значение вверху